# How to stop re-buffering when rewind or fast forward with AVPlay API on Tizen?

Tags: avplayer, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I am building an application for Tizen OS that has an archive playback functionality and now I want to fastForward or Rewind the video but after clicking the button it always starts buffering. This is bad for user experience, so I want to somehow eliminate it. How can I do it?

Here is the code for rewind:

```
var successCallback = function () {
   console.log("Media seek successful");
};

var errorCallback = function () {
   console.log("Media seek failed");
};

var currentTime = webapis.avplay.getCurrentTime();
var newTime = currentTime - length;

webapis.avplay.seekTo(newTime, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

I also tried to add the code to set the buffer size but it doesn't seem to work:

```
webapis.avplay.setBufferingParam(
  "PLAYER_BUFFER_FOR_PLAY",
  "PLAYER_BUFFER_SIZE_IN_SECOND",
  60);
```